# Como crear una url personalizada en wordpress para un termino de búsqueda

Tags: php, wordpress

Quisiera saber si es posible crear una url amigable para un termino en búsqueda en especifico, por ejemplo:

```
http://miweb.com/?s=75
```

y que esa búsqueda también se pueda hacer de esta manera:

```
http://miweb.com/buscando
```

la idea es ocultar el 75.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: lo ignoro por completo pero me dio más curiosidad saber porqué o para qué hacerlo ?

Comment: el termino de búsqueda arroja una especie de filtro, entonces me gustaría crear un apartado donde la gente solo al cliquear los mande a ese apartado pero el problema es que el 75 no se ve muy bien estéticamente, y el apartado va referido a una especie de categoría. como puede ser celulcares, precios. etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes crear un rewrite, algo así:

agregar a `functions.php` en el child-theme o custom theme

```
// rewrite Rules
// https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/5413/62765
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', 'wp_insertMyRewriteRules' );
function wp_insertMyRewriteRules( $rules )
{
  $newrules = [
    '^busqueda/?$' => 'index.php?s=75',
    '^busqueda2/?$' => 'index.php?s=76',
    '^buscando-celulares/?$' => 'index.php?s=78',
  ];
  return $newrules + $rules;
}

// Remember to flush_rules() when adding rules
add_filter( 'init', 'flushRules' );
function flushRules(){
  global $wp_rewrite;
  $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
```

- se agrega la regla al array de reglas de reescritura.
- si empieza(`^`) y termina(`$`) con `busqueda` y opcionalmente(`?`) con `/`
- se flushean las rules ( también funciona yendo a permalink en las settings y dandole save )

Ref: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/5413/62765

Para mas "editabilidad" podes poner un array en una constante visible al inicio del archivo:

```
define(
  'MIS_REDIRECCIONES_SEARCH',
  [
    'busqueda' => 75,
    'busqueda2' => 76,
    'buscando-celulares' => 78,
  ]
);

// rewrite Rules
// https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/5413/62765
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', 'wp_insertMyRewriteRules' );
function wp_insertMyRewriteRules( $rules )
{
  $newrules = [];
  foreach ( MIS_REDIRECCIONES_SEARCH as $slug => $numero ){
    $newrules[ '^'. $slug .'/?$' ] = 'index.php?s=' . $numero;
  }
  return $newrules + $rules;
}

// Remember to flush_rules() when adding rules
add_filter( 'init', 'flushRules' );
function flushRules(){
  global $wp_rewrite;
  $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
```

Comment: esto va en el archivo functions.php?

Comment: gracias pero no me funciona, aun sigue apareciendo el 75

Comment: al poner `http://miweb.com/busqueda` ?

Comment: :O vale perfecto! jaja ahora si funciono!! gracias crack

Comment: otra pregunta. Si quiero agregar otro valor ademas del 75, ejemplo;

si quiero buscar el 76 esta ves con una palabra diferente a "busqueda"

Comment: te pongo unas variantes

Comment: Muchas gracias !! era lo que estaba buscando...funciona perfecto